# How should one think about presheaf or a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

Given a topological space $X$, a presheaf $F$ of some algebraic structure on $X$ is defined such that

$(1)$ for each open set $U \subseteq X$, there is an algebraic structure $F(U)$,

$(2)$ for every inclusion $V \subseteq U$ of open subsets of $X$, there is a morphism $\rho_{U,V}:F(U) \to F(V)$ called the restriction map and it satisfies few properties.

I am often confused about the definition of presheaf. Sometimes it looks like a  functor on a category and sometimes it seems to be a collection of objects or a category.

How should one think about presheaf or a sheaf ?

Next, in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)), it says $F(U)$ is the $sections$ of the presheaf $F$ over the open set $U$, which is defined as $\Gamma(U,F)$ sometimes. What are these $sections$ ?

Are these one-way inverse function that we know in algebraic topology or algebraic geometry ?

For example, let $R$ be a commutative ring and $R$-Mod be the category of $R$-module, then $\text{Hom}_R(-,M)$ is a contravariant functor from the category $R$-Mod to $Ab$, the category of abelian groups. Can we think a presheaf $F$ to be $F:=\text{Hom}_R(-,M)$ in this case ? and then the sections are really functions $s \in F(N)=\text{Hom}_R(N,M)$.

Any comments and explanations are welcome

Comment: "Sections" is simply a name for elements of $F(U)$. There's nothing more to that. And your "example" isn't valid, you don't even have a topological space there! And "yes", (pre)sheaf is a contravariant functor. From a category $O(X)$ of all open subsets of $X$ and inclusions between them, to some category $C$.

Comment: Your "more generally" is backwards. Every sheaf is a presheaf but not vice versa.

Comment: @ZhenLin, it was rather a language not mathematics. But I made a correction.

Comment: @freakish, thank you for your nice comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these one-way inverse function that we know in algebraic topology or algebraic geometry ?

They're related but much more general as the comments alluded to.

I think the term 'sections' comes from an alternative definition of a sheaf (which can be recovered from arbitrary sheaves using the Etale Space I think). It more resembles the construction of a vector bundle. Notice that the sections of a vector bundle do form a sheaf.

There are a number of ways to define sheaves. Let's say we define an Etale Space on $X$ to be a topological space $F$ and a local homomorphism $\pi: F \to X$ so that the stalks $F_p :=\pi^{-1}(x)$ are abelian groups and the group operations are compatible with the topology on $F$. This is the definition of a sheaf from Ahlfor's 'Complex Analysis'  but I think this kind of definition was used in Godement's 'Topologie Algébrique et Théorie des Faisceaux' according to Hartshorne.

From an Etale Space $\pi: F \to X$ we define a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$. Let $$\mathscr{F}(U) = \{f: U \to F\;|\; \pi \circ f = \operatorname{Id}_U\}.$$ That is, $\mathscr{F}(U)$ are the sections of $\pi$ on $U$. It will then take on the abelian group structure from the stalks  to form a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$ so that $\mathscr{F}_p \cong F_p$. Similarly, the restriction map is just restriction of functions.

I tend to prefer the usual definition since it is much simpler but I'm sure there are situations where the alternative definition is preferable. I like to think of sheaf or presheaf sections figuratively as functions on open sets, although the function intuition does not work as well for presheaves.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer